# Unable to Process the authenticateForTransportDiscovery \ validateMetadata request

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to submit an application to the App Store from Xcode, ***"Submit to App Store..."***

and I get this error message(s):

> *Unable to process the authenticateForTransportDiscovery request at this time due to a general error. (1240)*

and

> *Unable to process validateMetadata request at this time due to a general error (1019)*

[image]

is it a (another...) problem with Apple?

Comment: I had the error too with `Application Loader`. After trying again it went through. <br>However, I can't see my build at `iTunesConnect`, even after 1 hour.

Comment: I've had it once, and now it complains I have not optimized my app for iPhone 5, missing the Default-568h@2x splash screen even though it's been here for ages (I submitted a previous version 1 week ago fine)

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153630/getting-error-app-submission-to-itunes-store

Comment: I can see my application in the Prerelease section, but it's been sitting in the "Uploaded" state for a while now.

Comment: If your build stays in "Processing" state for more than 5 mintues - reupload it..it either gets stuck or succeeds in 1-2-3 minutes

Comment: It's actually not even getting to the "Processing" state, I've uploaded 2 builds and both are still at "Uploaded"

Comment: Weird. The most recent build of the two immediately jumped to an "Inactive" state (meaning I could actually use it) after 5 minutes. The older build disappeared entirely from the Prerelease section.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: @RichardSlater: Looks to me like this could be on-topic according BSMP's comment there? "The help center states that questions about software tools commonly used by programmers are on topic as long as it's also a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development." For example, I just ran into a real case where a programming error gave this error code reliably, but I can't add a real answer with "check that your metadata.xml contains a valid `apple_id` - it's a number, not your bundle id"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yeah same problem with me (using Application Loader). Here are my steps to resolve it.
- Sign out and close Application Loader
- Sign in and upload the build again. No need to re-archive app, just on

Comment: No need to sign out..just have to upload again

Answer (score 6):

Keep trying until it works. No need to rebuild. Just reupload.
For me it worked on the second time

Comment: +1 For this solution.  Did not have to go to Application Loader, just retried a few times from X-Code and was successful.

Comment: Yes. The whole day I'm uploading apps and some of them upload from 1st time..other from 3th time..just click back and send button again and wait...Apple's platform is so bad..

Answer (score 4):

Few hours ago this happened to me while using application loader. Just hit previous and re- try the operation. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I was using a VPN connection, I exited it and everything worked fine

Answer (score 2):

I also tried switching WiFi (maybe previous one was on VPN) and it was able to go through.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Application Loader it works fine.

Comment: Logout from Application Loader and make sure you select right Provider in top Of Application Loader and wait 20 minutes and try again every thing done

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem occurs because you have to agree the latest ios **Program License Agreement**.

You can do it here https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/

Comment: It was already accepted on my account when I had the problem.